# CFL bulbs using more watts then rated

Tags: lighting

When I run my CFL bulbs off the generator they use reduced watts. But when I switch them over to my dc-ac solar converter they use many times the watts they're suppose to according to my inline watt meter. Will getting a modified or pure sine wave converter reduce the watts to what they should use?

Comment: What waveform does your current inverter output?

Comment: If you have a cheap meter, it's likely neither true RMS nor aware of the difference between watts and VA. Both of these can cause it to over-read.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will have a big effect on it.  If you're familiar with the difference between Watts and VA... *that*.

Watts and VA normally differ when the load has poor power factor, but it could also be when the output is not sinewave and the load wants sinewave (e.g. a motor).

Perhaps it is drawing the correct wattage (or VA) but your tester is misreporting due to not knowing how to handle non-sinewave supply.